# JavaFX - variable passed from Controller 2 to Controller 1 updated correctly when checked with System.out but result not updating in label field

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have researched this topic for several days and cannot find an answer that solves my query so here goes - my first StackOverflow question. Be considerate!

I have an application with a side menu and a main pane of type BorderPane. In this main pane is TableView1. The contents of this pane are part of **Controller 1** called 'checksheet'. When I select an item in TableView1 and click a button, a new window pops up with another table (TableView2) into which I can add data. The contents of this window are part of **Controller 2** called 'Table2'.

In **Controller 1** I have a number of labels which should automatically update when I close the **Controller 2** window having added the relevant data to TableView2. To do this I have followed instructions on passing variables updated in **Controller 2** to **Controller 1** and all seems in order. I have also written a 'System.out.println' in the setLabel method in **Controller 1** to confirm whether or not the variable has been passed to **Controller 1** and is in the Label field - and yes it has been passed. It is seemingly there. However in the UI itself the Label field is not updating.

It appears that somehow the UI is not refreshing but the code itself that sits behind it is all in order. All fx:id values are assigned and all fx:controller values are also assigned in the FXML file.

Here is the method in **Controller 2** 'Table2' to call for updaing the label in **Controller 1** 'checksheet'

```
String data1 = Double.toString(lengthTD);               
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CheckSheetUI.fxml"));
            AnchorPane mainPane  = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Checksheet cs = loader.getController();             
            cs.setLabel2(data1);
```

Here is the setter in **Controller 1** 'checksheet'

```
public void setLabel2(String data2) {
totalToDateBox.setText(data2);
System.out.println(totalToDateBox.getText()); // this does return the correct value in the console }
```

Any ideas as to why the label in the UI "ChecksSheetUI.fxml" is not updating? I feel it's something to do with dealing with border panes as I have followed code elsewhere and this doesn't seem to work.

As an aside (in case its relevant) I have an over-arching controller which deals with adjusting what is contained in the main pane (as I have several unrelated FXML files which are linked).

```
public class FXMLDocumentController extends Main {

@FXML
public BorderPane mainPane;

@FXML
private Button btn_dmg27, btn_staySafe, btn_checkSheet;

@FXML
private void buttonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    if(event.getSource() == btn_dmg27) 
    {
        Parent parent1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dmg27UI.fxml"));           
        mainPane.setCenter(parent1);

    }
    else if(event.getSource() == btn_staySafe) 
    {
        Parent parent1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("staySafeUI.fxml"));            
        mainPane.setCenter(parent1);        

    }
    else if(event.getSource() == btn_checkSheet) 
    {
        Parent parent1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CheckSheetUI.fxml"));          
        mainPane.setCenter(parent1);        
    } }
```

Comment: Do you actually display the newly loaded scene or is that just some throwaway scene you created to have a target to pass the info to, but drop it without ever adding it to a scene shown in a window?

Comment: The intention is to reload it into the controller 1 scene. Do I need more code? I opened a brand new window in previous attempts and that worked but I couldn't figure out how to reload the main pane of the border pane. I had a null pointer even when I wrote a getter method for that pane which is declared in a separate controller.

Comment: what we need to help you find your error is a [mcve] demonstrating it :)

Answer (score -1):

just guessing as on mobile on the road (train). I would suggest you keep your data 'stored' in the overall Controller. If your subcontrollers change values there, other elements can display it. Look into MVC. - Another thing to consider is 'bindings'. Bind the label text to your 'data' - variable. As soon you change that value, it will be displayed in the GUI. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try to input some text on the label on scenebuilder to test properties of the label .